# Remove b' prefix from CSV

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am doing a Udacity course to convert OSM data into csv and it seems like due to the fact that I am using Python 3, my csv outputs all have a b' prefix infront. After reading through a few threads, I figured it has something to do with utf-8 encoding.

Here is an example of my output when I run this:

```
import csv
with open('nodes_tags - TEST.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

```
["b'id'", "b'key'", "b'value'", "b'type'"]
[]
["b'25451918'", "b'ref'", "b'2A'", "b'regular'"]
[]
["b'25451918'", "b'highway'", "b'motorway_junction'", "b'regular'"]
[]
["b'25455287'", "b'ref'", "b'14A'", "b'regular'"]
```

Is there a quick way to clean the csv files itself and remove the 'b?

Comment: Can you post several lines of the csv file? It looks like the "b"'s are in the file, suggesting that the problem is in whatever wrote the file.

Comment: "I am doing a Udacity course to convert OSM data into csv".  If you are reading the result of this conversion, show us the conversion code.  It's doing it wrong.